# Why is PHP doing this?

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>  
        <meta charset= "UTF-8" >
    </head>
  <body>

    <?php
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $number = $_POST['number'];
   
     echo "Hello" . $username ;
     
     echo "In 10 years, you will be" . $number + 10 ;
     
    ?>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

so on my live server this code pops up with the users name and age, but there are no spaces in-between the words and it does not add 10 years to the $number. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "Hello" . $username ;
```

There is no space because you have not added a space to the end of the "Hello" string. Just add a space to fix that.

```
echo "Hello " . $username ;
```

---

```
echo "In 10 years, you will be" . $number + 10 ;
```

This is a result of string operations. Just put your numerical operation in parentheses.

```
echo "In 10 years, you will be" . ($number + 10);
```

Comment: Thank you so much David! I have many more questions, but can only post every 90 minutes. Is there a way I could reach you? If not, no worries :)